# jQuery $.ajax function won't accept the array I'm trying to post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, post

I am trying to post data to a script on my own server through the jQuery $.ajax function in the following way:

```
var data = {};
var date = new Date();
data.selectedDate = selectedDate;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.url.com/somescript.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: this.data,
        async: false,
    })
```

If I remove the data parameter the script gets called. Can any one explain what's going wrong?

Comment: Don't you have to use JSON.stringify when you do $.ajax like that (e.g. data: JSON.stringify(this.data) )?

Comment: what does this refer to?

Comment: @Dharman: what does *what* refer to? (Couldn't resist.)

Comment: you never defined `selectedDate`.

Comment: I meant `this.` as in `this.data`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some one suggested this earlier but his post seems to have been deleted. JSON ecoding the data prior to posting fixed the problem. I'm not sure why I suddenly need to do this as I have posted to this server before with out json encoding my data, maybe it's cause I'm working on a public wifi.

```
JSON.stringify(this.data)
```

Thanks to every one for the help.

Answer (score 4):

`this.data` is not `data`. One is a variable, the other is a property on the current context.

`selectedDate` is undefined when you try to assign it to `data.date`. You assigned the `new Date()` to `var date` not `var selectedDate`.

```
var data = {};
var date = new Date();
data.selectedDate = date;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.example.com/somescript.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        async: false,
    })
```

Comment: Hi Quentin, You are correct I omitted a line of code where I assigned date to this.data for the class where the $.ajax function lives.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var date = new Date();
var data = { selectedDate: date};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.url.com/somescript.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    async: false,
})
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do it. Either way I define the array I get the expected {"selectedDate":"2013-01-25T20:48:26.490Z"} as the value for this.data